# Regex with 2 conditions at least 1 must be good

Tags: regex

im trying to make a regular expression with 2 conditions,at least 1 of that 2 conditions has to be true, but both true is also allowed.
this is my regex:

```
\(?<=\]\s)(word1|word2)(?=\s\[)\
```

the `(?<=\]\s)` or `(?=\s\[)` has to be true, but they may also both be true, but at least 1!

```
example:
] word1 - true
word1 [- true
] word1 [- true
word1 - false
```

the match has always to bo on the first result (in the result array so 'output_array[0] has to be 'word1') so thats why i don't want to use `|`
thanks for helping

Comment: so you want to match either `word1` or `word2`, and not both? is that correct?

Comment: could you give an example for each case ?

Comment: It would be helpful to have some example input.

Comment: that the result array index from the result always has to be the same

Answer (score 4):

The only relatively easy solution I can think of would be to copy the word list and separate them into two options:

```
((?<=\]\s)(word1|word2)|(word1|word2)(?=\s\[))
```

---

**Edit:** An alternative would be `(\]\s)?(word1|word2)(?=(?(1)|\s\[))`. This only requires one list of words to be inserted. Keep in mind that I've removed the lookbehind from this one, and replaced it with a group - *this might not be what you're looking for*, depending on your requirements. I've used the regex101 page that Jerry linked to to test it: http://regex101.com/r/mB7vM2 (thank you Jerry).

Comment: And what if there are 3 words? Or 5? You just keep exponentially expanding to 5*5 = 25 terms then?

Comment: There will only be two word lists, so wouldn't that be 2*5? But yes, that's essentially what this would do. Optionally the word list can be stored in a variable and inserted into the SQL query dynamically during runtime.

Comment: I've edited my post to show an alternative that only requires one list of words.

Answer (score 3):

How about having a big `or`?

```
(?<=\]\s)(word1|word2)|(word1|word2)(?=\s\[)
```

Tested [here](http://regex101.com/r/oC3vR1).

EDIT: This one will return `word1` or `word2` in the same result array:

```
((?<=\]\s)(?:word1|word2)|(?:word1|word2)(?=\s\[))
```

And retested [here](http://regex101.com/r/eV8pZ1).

Comment: @Jerry: +1, 2nd attempt is better but it doesn't avoid repeating words. If there are large # of words then its not a scalable solution.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. I'm not sure what you mean by large number of words though. If that's so, then trying to match word by word through regex won't be the solution since regex is based on patterns. What can be done then would be to use `((?<=\]\s)(?:\w+)|(?:\w+)(?=\s\[))` (or something more or less restrictive depending on the situation) and then check each word against a dic.

Comment: What I meant was this. What if you need to match `(w1|w2|w3|w4|w5|w6|w7)` then you will need to repeat whole words again. IMO conditional patterns as in @CasimiretHippolyte answer is the way to go (if available).

Comment: @anubhava I see, but the OP explicitly wants the word to be in the first match, a condition not satisfied by the conditional :(

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that is to use a conditional test (if supported), example:

```
(?<=(\])\s|)(word1|word2)(?(-2)|(?=\s\[))
```

Comment: @anubhava: -2 refers to the second capturing group on the left from the conditionnal offset. in this case it is (\]). It is a relative notation. But if you want you can use an absolute notation ?(1)

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation about relative capturing group. Learnt a new concept :)